# Go: XML Unmarshal Nested Structs into interface{}

Tags: xml, go, struct, interface

I come from a Python background and this is my first proper foray into Go so I don't think things are clicking quite yet.

I'm currently implementing the Affiliate Window XML API in Go. The API follows a standard structure for Requests and Responses so to that end I'm trying to keep things dry. Envelopes always have the same structure, something like this:

```xml
<Envelope>
    <Header></Header>
    <Body></Body>
</Envelope>
```

The contents `Header` and `Body` will be different depending on what I'm requesting and the response so I created a base `Envelope` `struct`

```golang
type Envelope struct {
    XMLName xml.Name    `xml:"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/ Envelope"`
    NS1     string      `xml:"xmlns:ns1,attr"`
    XSD     string      `xml:"xmlns:xsd,attr"`
    Header  interface{} `xml:"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/ Header"`
    Body    interface{} `xml:"Body"`
}
```

This works well for marshaling the XML for a request but I'm having problems with unmarshaling:

```golang
func NewResponseEnvelope(body interface{}) *Envelope {
    envelope := NewEnvelope()
    envelope.Header = &ResponseHeader{}
    envelope.Body = body
    return envelope
}

func main() {
    responseBody := &GetMerchantListResponseBody{}
    responseEnvelope := NewResponseEnvelope(responseBody)

    b := bytes.NewBufferString(response)
    xml.NewDecoder(b).Decode(responseEnvelope)
    fmt.Println(responseEnvelope.Header.Quota) // Why can't I access this?
}
```

This http://play.golang.org/p/v-MkfEyFPM probably describes the problem better in code than I can in words :p

Thanks,

Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type of the `Header` field inside the `Envelope` struct is `interface{}` which is **not** a `struct` so you cannot refer to any of its fields.

In order to refer to a field named `Quota`, you have to declare `Header` with a static type which contains a `Quota` field, something like this:

```
type HeaderStruct struct {
    Quota string
}

type Envelope struct {
    // other fields omitted
    Header HeaderStruct
}
```

If you don't know what type it will be or you can't commit to a single type, you can leave it as `interface{}`, but then you have to use either [Type switches](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Switch_statements) or [Type assertion](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions) to convert it to a static type at runtime, the latter would look something like this:

```
headerStruct, ok := responseEnvelope.Header.(HeaderStruct)
// if ok is true, headerStruct is of type HeaderStruct
// else responseEnvelope.Header is not of type HeaderStruct
```

Another option would be to use reflection to access named fields of the `Envelope.Header` value, but try to solve it in other ways if possible. If you're interested in learning more about reflection in Go, I recommend reading [The Laws of Reflection](http://blog.golang.org/laws-of-reflection) blog post first.